# Is it possible to create a virtual machine from a timeshift snapshot?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, backup, manjaro

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a virtual machine from a backup that was created with the [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) program? I am using Manjaro Linux but I would like to create a virtual machine from a snapshot/backup created of my current local machine - something I could then import to VirtualBox for example.

Something similar would be the [VMWare Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html) program.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A Snapshot is a temporary file that must be (in the VM) either discarded or combined. It is not a backup and you cannot start with a snapshot and make a whole machine.

Just install your virtual machine from the Linux ISO file.

I have done that here (and I am working in a Linux VM so created) and it works great.

If you have a working machine, you can normally use VCenter VMware Converter to make a Virtual Machine (not an install ISO).  You need the Linux variants, and install Converter on the machine you wish to convert.  This certainly works in Windows. Try it on your Linux machine.

Comment: Well is there a way to create a iso file from my current local machine?

Comment: You should be able to make a VM from your current machine and I amended my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Do you know if such a program also exists for Virtualbox or is this currently only available for VMWare?

Comment: I do not know about Vbox, but VMware has this.  You need to check the Vbox site